# Asp.NET CORE WEB API with a COM OBJECT

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having issues on how to handle multiple call to my webApi.

The controllers of my webApi are using a com object who need to connect to a database and only allow one connection at a time.

Let's say i got 2 controllers :

-Clients

-Invoices

If "Clients" and "Invoices" are called at the same time, the first operation will fail.

Is it possible to make multiple Controllers wait for the end of the task ?
Or is there any other solutions ?

Comment: simplest possible fix: put a "proxy" class in front of your com-object and let that `lock` on something to prevent concurrency.

Comment: I would invest in IoC and inject a 'Domain' or as @FranzGleichmann says a proxy class that handles locking. Make sure you instantiate the Domain object via IoC container in singleton scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple repository pattern to solve your problem. The repositories are a special kind of `Facade` that hide the implementation details of your database access and return domain models

Example:

```
public class DataObjectRepository: IDataObjectRepository {
      private static readonly object x = new object();
 
      public DataObject GetObject() {
          lock (x)
         {
                  // Your code accessing the COM object
          }
      }
}
```

Then inject it as singleton

```
services.AddSingleton<IDataObjectRepository, DataObjectRepository>();
```

Replace `DataObject` with any domain model name.

Comment: Ok so i created 3 repositories 

- ComRepository
- ClientRepository
- InvoiceRepository
Client and Invoice Repo are using the instance created in ComRepository.
And it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers.